# Granting permission for Windows service

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, iis, powershell

I am on yet another obstacle. I have a non-admin IIS identity account, to which I would like to grant permission to start, stop, restart, and read the status of one Windows Service. I followed the solution posted here. However, I would like to achieve this via PowerShell to automate, because I have so many servers. I was able to get SID of non-admin account, and get the output of command and save it under a variable. I converted to string, but cannot apply any functions such as `StartsWith`, `split`, `insert`, etc. Here is my code:

```
#Getting the SID for non-admin ISS identity account
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("non-admin")
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
$sid = $strSID.Value
#output retuned = S-1-5-21-2103278432-2794320136-1883075150-1000

#Storing the output of cmd prompt
$cmd = cmd.exe /c "sc sdshow <Service_Name>"
$test = $cmd | Out-String
#output returned = D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)

#Storing the value that needs to be inserted in $CMD
$str = "(A;;RPWPCR;;;$sid)"
```

I would like to insert $str just before "S:" in $test and I have been unsuccessful. I would like to achieve this by PowerShell and not SubInAcl. Any help would be appreciated. The final code should look like below:

```
sc sdset <SERVICE_NAME> "D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)($str)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `$test` variable contains `D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)`,  you could do:

```
$sid = "S-1-5-21-2103278432-2794320136-1883075150-1000"
$test = "D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)"
$str = "(A;;RPWPCR;;;$sid)"

$newstring = $test -replace "S:","$($str)S:"

$newstring
```

returns:

```
D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;RPWPCR;;;S-1-5-21-2103278432-2794320136-1883075150-1000)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @Cory Knutson. I had to replace `$str = "(A;;RPWPCR;;;$sid)S:"`  because `$str` should be after `S:`. However, I am trying to execute the command by passing in variable and I am getting errors in executing the final command.

Comment: **Update**:Thank you for the help @Cory Knutson. I had to replace `$str = "(A;;RPWPCR;;;$sid)S:"`  because `$str` should be after `S:`. However, I am trying to execute the command by passing in variable but this doesn't seem to grant permissions to the account. I am trying something like this `$arg="sc sdset <Service_Name> $newString"` and then `Powershell -command "Start-Process 'cmd' -Verb RunAS -ArgumentList '/c $arg' "`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: So, $args output is as follows `sc sdset <Service_name>` and on new line `$newString` shows up. When this happens, CMD throws an error "[sc] Access is denied 5:".However, When I run the command manually in single line of code then the permissions were granted.

Comment: Are you running the Powershell console that you are trying this from as elevated for UAC?

Comment: I am a local admin on the Server and running it as same. Like I stated, I think the problem is that `$args` has two lines and this where it throws an error. I believe, if somehow, I am able to get `(sc sdset "$newString")` on one line of code instead of two then things would be more pleasant.Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how you are getting two lines. When I run the code I posted, it comes back with one line.

Comment: This is the output I am getting when I `echo $args`

`$args = "Sc sdset AppIDSvc `"$newString`" `

`Sc sdset AppIDSvc " \n
D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;RPWPCR;;;S-1-5-21-1985857054-386131273-3228901743-1010)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
"`
I want it to be 

`Sc sdset AppIDSvc "D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;RPWPCR;;;S-1-5-21-1985857054-386131273-3228901743-1010)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)"`

Comment: \n is where I have blank spaces then followed by SDDL format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67591/discussion-between-cory-knutson-and-sid).

Comment: Thank you for your help @cory Knutson. I have marked this as an answer. I was able to fix it by changing this command `$test = [string]$cmd`